# PowerShell changing value in a JSON file

Tags: json, powershell

I am trying to change the value with a JSON file.  Not getting the expected result and when trying to load the value from a C# app it throws up.

Content of the JSON file:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "Kestrel": {

    "Endpoints": {
      "Http": {
        "Url": "http://localhost:8004"
      }
    }

  }
}
```

I am trying to change the URL to: http://localhost:0

Here is the sample code I have:

```
$pathToJson = "D:\Temp\appsettings.json"
$a = Get-Content $pathToJson | ConvertFrom-Json
$a.Kestrel.Endpoints.Http.Url = "http://localhost:0"
$a | ConvertTo-Json | set-content $pathToJson
```

The result is not what is expected and as mentioned above throws an exception in the event viewer:

```
{
    "Logging":  {
                    "LogLevel":  {
                                     "Default":  "Information",
                                     "Microsoft":  "Warning",
                                     "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime":  "Information"
                                 }
                },
    "AllowedHosts":  "*",
    "Kestrel":  {
                    "Endpoints":  {
                                      "Http":  "@{Url=http://localhost:0}"
                                  }
                }
}
```

Look at the HTTP URL.
Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: You're missing `-Depth` parameter, `"@{Url=http://localhost:0}"` is a consequence of this. See linked answer for more details.